# Scala and Akka - Testing actors as a system with Akka Testkit

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, akka-testkit

In my Scala application say I have Actor `A` and Actor `B`. I want to devise a test case in ScalaTest that would allow me to send a message to Actor `A` and see what message it sends to Actor `B` in order to see if `A` is properly processing it's data and sending the right message to `B`. How would one test this? It took me a long time to get this cooked up on my own...but it does seem to mostly work.

```
class A extends Actor { ... }

class B extends Actor { ... }

class C(p: TestProbe) extends B {
  override def receive = {
    LoggingReceive {
      case x =>
        println(x.toString)
        p.ref ! x
    }
  }
}

case class MsgToB(...)

// Spec class which extends TestKit
"A" should {
  "send the right message to B" {
    val p = TestProbe()
    val a = TestActorRef[A]
    val c = TestActorRef(Props(new C(p)))

    // Assume A has a reference to C. Not shown here.
    a ! msg
    // Assert messages
    p.expectMsgType[MsgToB]
  }
}
```

Is this the best means of doing this? Is there a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like what you want is to test the behaviour of actor A in isolation. In order to do this, you need to be able to control how actor A gets its reference to actor B. For example, you could provide the reference in the actor's constructor:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Props}

class A(refToB: ActorRef) extends Actor { ... }

object A {
  def props(refToB: ActorRef): Props = Props(new A(refToB))
}
```

There are alternative ways you can pass the reference to actor B to actor A, but using the constructor is arguably the easiest choice. In the example above, we also provide a method for creating the correct `Props` for the actor.

Now that you can control the reference to actor B, you can replace the actor reference with test probe in tests.

```
import akka.testkit.TestProbe

// Initialise a test probe
val probe = TestProbe()

// Actor A with reference to actor B replaced with the test probe
val a = system.actorOf(A.props(probe.ref))

// Send a message to actor A
a ! someMessage

// Verify that the probe received a correct response from actor A
p.expectMsgType[MsgToB]
```

Notice that I created the actor using the actor system from the TestKit instead of using the `TestActorRef`. This means that the actor message processing will be asynchronous instead of synchronous. Personally, I've found the asynchronous testing style to be a better fit because it better represents how the actor is run in a production system. [Asynchronous testing is also recommended in the official documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/testing.html#Synchronous_Unit_Testing_with_TestActorRef).

Comment: I like this. I went with the original implementation because I had to do something but this sounds interesting. The goal is to test the whole actor system from our entry actor that handles web requests to the whole chain of (mocked) service calls we do and verify out data output as well as the web response. One challenge was getting the async behavior so that assertions don't need to be ordered. If this works that solves it.